# Retrieve values from array.xml and check it in main activity

Tags: java, android

I have no clear working knowledge of retrieving values from an XML file and how to use it effectively.
Can some one help me understand,how to do it?

Here my  file and in my main activity.what i need to do,
is-i will select an operator from settings then I will check for the exact operator name and will retrieve couple of desired strings from a class named CallManager and will call by another code segmentation.
 i did it for a single operator where preString and internal digit size was fixed.So it was no problem.But i need to do for couple of them,-taking name from preferences.please help.thanks-Piyal

```
<string-array name="operatormodes">
    <item >Airtel</item>
    <item >Banglalink</item>
    <item >Grameen Phone</item>
    <item >Robi</item>
    <item >TeleTalk</item>
</string-array>



prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

  // Operator
  prefs.edit().putString(PreferencesActivity.KEY_OPERATOR_MODE, CaptureActivity.DEFAULT_OPERATOR_MODE).commit();


  // Retrieve from preferences, and set in this Activity, the Operator mode
  String[] operatorModes = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.operatormodes);
  String operatorModeName = prefs.getString(PreferencesActivity.KEY_OPERATOR_MODE, operatorModes[0]);
  Log.w("im changed", "Airtel");
  if (operatorModeName.equals(operatorModes[0])) 
  {
      callManager.setOperatorName("Airtel");
      callManager.setOperatorBasedInternalDigit("Airtel");
      callManager.setOperatorBasedInternalPreString("Airtel");
      callManager.setPreString(callManager.internalPreString);
  }
  else if (operatorModeName.equals(operatorModes[1])) 
  {
      callManager.setOperatorName("Banglalink");
      callManager.setOperatorBasedInternalDigit("Banglalink");
      callManager.setOperatorBasedInternalPreString("Banglalink");
      callManager.setPreString(callManager.internalPreString);
  }
  else if (operatorModeName.equals(operatorModes[2])) 
  {
      callManager.setOperatorName("Grameen Phone");
      callManager.setOperatorBasedInternalDigit("Grameen Phone");
      callManager.setOperatorBasedInternalPreString("Grameen Phone");
      callManager.setPreString(callManager.internalPreString);
  }

  else if (operatorModeName.equals(operatorModes[3])) 
  {
      callManager.setOperatorName("Robi");
      callManager.setOperatorBasedInternalDigit("Robi");
      callManager.setOperatorBasedInternalPreString("Robi");
      callManager.setPreString(callManager.internalPreString);
  }

  else if (operatorModeName.equals(operatorModes[4])) 
  {
      callManager.setOperatorName("TeleTalk");
      callManager.setOperatorBasedInternalDigit("TeleTalk");
      callManager.setOperatorBasedInternalPreString("TeleTalk");
      callManager.setPreString(callManager.internalPreString);
  }


  prefs.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(listener);
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is not very clear, but i hope this snippet should help you:

```
  String[] operatorModes = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.operatormodes);
  String operatorModeName = prefs.getString(PreferencesActivity.KEY_OPERATOR_MODE, operatorModes[0]);
  Log.w("im changed", operatorModeName);
  for(int i = 0; i < operatorModes.length; i++) {
      if (operatorModeName.equals(operatorModes[i])) 
      {
          callManager.setOperatorName(operatorModeName);
          callManager.setOperatorBasedInternalDigit(operatorModeName);
          callManager.setOperatorBasedInternalPreString(operatorModeName);
          callManager.setPreString(callManager.internalPreString);
      }
  }    

  prefs.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(listener);
```

Comment: But,i have to send fixed operator name to CallManager,then it will give a finalString variables value.